# Undefined type Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

Need someone to help me with this issue. Laravel Sanctum

I've installed basic default laravel 8++ on my local server.

I follow the instruction of Laravel Sanctum. But I stuck on getting the **HasApiTokens**

```
1. composer require laravel/sanctum
2. php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"
3. php artisan migrate
```

I add in my **kernel.php** like below

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

And in **config>auth.php**, I changed the driver to 'sanctum'

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ], 
    ],
```

And here's my **composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.1",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I tried to import/use Laravel/Sanctum/HasApiTokens, it says '**undefined type**'. Image as below

[image]

Here's another screenshot. Doesn't have any sanctum directory after Laravel.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `composer update`? do you still get the same issue?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG ,  I did run the composer update, config clear / cache, composer dump-autoload still not work. I'm using php 7.4 version.

Comment: When you run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"`, did you get any error?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG, Nope . I don't have any error. successfully migrated and installed.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does `vendor/laravel/sanctum` exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess `SanctumServiceProvider` is not automatically registered in your application. To resolve your issue, you should add the service provider manually in `config/app.php`.

```
'providers' => [
    //...
    Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider::class,
];
```

Comment: Thanks bro. After I add this line in app.php, I still can't call the sanctum in app/models/user.php. I have to close visual studio code and reopen the project then I can call sanctum in the list.

Comment: You're welcome. I upvote because your question is clear.

Answer (score 6):

Just close and reopen the vscode

[image]